# Halo 3 legendary ending

Tags: halo-3

If I want to watch Halo 3's extended "legendary" ending, do I have to beat the entire campaign on Legendary difficulty, or could I just beat it on Easy and then beat the final mission on Legendary?

Comment: You don't have to beat the campaign at all - just YouTube it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You only need to complete the **final mission on Legendary**. The difficulty setting for the rest of the campaign is irrelevant. This has been [confirmed by other players](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080717173309AAsJlIY) as well.